# Cannot access property of an existing node package because it is 'undefined'. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress

I've been having a play with with node.js - building a Wordpress setup tool, using the wp-cli package as a dependency. I had a functional package which performed several steps (downloading files, creating a config/local database, performing some WP admin tasks, et al), but it was a prime example of Callback Hell so I opted to distribute the load across an object.

Below is a stripped down module illustrating my attempt to do this, up to the point where it is failing. I've also posted the error message received.

I'll reiterate that everything worked fine before the refactor - I know that the *config*/*options* objects are valid and the *wp-cli* package definitely works. I've used the technique 'var foo = this;' to retain context in past projects, but the error would seem to suggest that wpcli is not being retained.

Any advice will be appreciated!

---

**Code:**

```
module.exports = function(config, options) {

    var wpcli = require('wp-cli');

    function WpInstaller (wpcli, config, options) {
        this.wpcli = wpcli;
        this.config = config;
        this.options = options;
        this.init();
    };

    WpInstaller.prototype.init = function() {
        var wpinst = this;
        wpinst.wpcli.discover({path: wpinst.options.name.default}, function() {
            wpinst.downloadCore();
        });
    };

    WpInstaller.prototype.downloadCore = function() {
        var wpinst = this;
        wpinst.wpcli.core.download(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return false;
            wpinst.setupConfig();
        });
    };

    new WpInstaller(wpcli, config, options);
};
```

---

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'download' of undefined
    at WpInstaller.downloadCore (/Users/john/dev/wpack/lib/wordpress.js:38:18)
    at /Users/john/dev/wpack/lib/wordpress.js:31:11
    at /Users/john/dev/wpack/node_modules/wp-cli/lib/WP.js:119:3
    at /Users/john/dev/wpack/node_modules/wp-cli/lib/commands.js:76:4
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:735:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wpcli.discover()` is a [static method](https://github.com/gtg092x/node-wp-cli/blob/3d7d9daa9c100f6030bdbc95ad399fc3f03475d6/lib/WP.js#L23) that [creates a new `WP` instance](https://github.com/gtg092x/node-wp-cli/blob/3d7d9daa9c100f6030bdbc95ad399fc3f03475d6/lib/WP.js#L31) and [passes that instance to the callback](https://github.com/gtg092x/node-wp-cli/blob/3d7d9daa9c100f6030bdbc95ad399fc3f03475d6/lib/WP.js#L115). [That instance is what contains the commands](https://github.com/gtg092x/node-wp-cli/blob/3d7d9daa9c100f6030bdbc95ad399fc3f03475d6/README.md#usage). So try something like this:

```
var wpcli = require('wp-cli');

function WpInstaller (config, options) {
  this.wp = null;
  this.config = config;
  this.options = options;
  this.init();
};
WpInstaller.prototype.init = function() {
  var wpinst = this;
  wpcli.discover({path: wpinst.options.name.default}, function(wp) {
    wpinst.wp = wp;
    wpinst.downloadCore();
  });
};
WpInstaller.prototype.downloadCore = function() {
  var wpinst = this;
  wpinst.wp.core.download(function(err, res) {
    if (err) return false;
    wpinst.setupConfig();
  });
};

module.exports = function(config, options) {
  new WpInstaller(config, options);
};
```